# Eclipse compiler lambda parameter type signature

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, bytecode, eclipse-jdt

Given the following Java code:

```
public interface HasUniqueKey<Key> {
  Key getInternId();
}

public class Util {
  public static List<Integer> toIntegerList(List<? extends HasUniqueKey<Integer>> entities) {
    return entities.stream().map(m -> m.getInternId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Eclipse Mars and Neon (haven't tested others) are producing the following bytecode for the lambda (as seen with `javap -v -p -c -l -s -constants`):

```
private static java.lang.Integer lambda$0(HasUniqueKey);
    descriptor: (LHasUniqueKey;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokeinterface #68,  1           // InterfaceMethod HasUniqueKey.getInternId:()Ljava/lang/Object;
         6: checkcast     #74                 // class java/lang/Integer
         9: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 8: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      10     0     m   LHasUniqueKey;
      LocalVariableTypeTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      10     0     m   !+LHasUniqueKey<Ljava/lang/Integer;>;
```

I'm quite puzzled as to this last signature for parameter `m`: `!+LHasUniqueKey<Ljava/lang/Integer;>;`. It doesn't seem to comply with [the JLS definition on signatures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9.1), the "!+" is invalid there (and I have no idea what "!" means in this context).

The `javac` compiler doesn't produce `LocalVariableTypeTable` metadata, since that is intended for debuggers only.

Can anyone provide some insight as to what this signature means? Is this a bug on Eclipse JDT?

Comment: `javac` does produce metadata if you pass -g:all.